# Can't pip install lxml

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am getting this error [I have installed setuptools already]

> Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;__file__='C:\Users\YASHOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_yashoraja\lxml\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\YASHOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9akmmco4-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\YASHOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_yashoraja\lxml

Comment: What does this have to do with Visual Studio?

Comment: I am actually using visual studio (virtual env) to pip install it, but fair, I have removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build it on Windows.
Instructions and binaries on their web site:

https://lxml.de/installation.html

https://lxml.de/installation.html#source-builds-on-ms-windows

Personally, I had a similar issue with pyaudio and I just gave up and did my project on Linux.